# Natural Deduction $(∀x∃y (P(x) → Q(y))) → (∃y∀x(P(x) → Q(y)))$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I am having trouble with this Natural Deduction question

$$(∀x∃y (P(x) → Q(y))) → (∃y∀x(P(x) → Q(y)))$$

Comment: If "For every person there is a moon such that if the person is smaller than $2$ meters, the moon orbits the earth.", then "There is a moon such that for every person, if the person is smaller than $2$ meters, then the moon orbits the earth." The point is that you can put distinct objects into $P$ and $Q$, and so if some $y$ has property $Q$, then you can use that same $y$ for all implications on the left hand side.

Comment: Ooops was evidently having a serious "senior moment" last night answering this. Oh dear! Apologies for any confusion/upset caused.

Comment: If you happen to already know how to prove, in the relevant natural deduction system, that formulas are equivalent to their prenex forms, then it may be useful to observe that both the antecedent and the consequent of the implication in your question are prenex forms of $(\exists x\,P(x))\to(\exists y\,Q(y))$.

Answer (score 4):

I will use *natural deduction* rules according to Ian Chiswell & Wilfrid Hodges, [Mathematical Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199215626) (2007) [see **Appendix A**, page 217-on, for a summary of the rules].

*Proof*

Assume the *antecedent* :

> $∀x∃y(P(x)→Q(y))$ --- (A)

Then, by $\forall$-elimination :

$∃y(P(a)→Q(y))$

Assume $b$ for $\exists$-elimination :

$P(a)→Q(b)$ --- (B)

By $\forall$-introduction :

> $\forall x(P(x)→Q(b))$

and by $\exists$-intorduction :

> $\exists y\forall x(P(x)→Q(y))$.

Due to the fact that the "auxiliary" *term* $b$ is nor longer present in the conclusion, nor in the assumption (A), we can apply $\exists$-elimination and discharge (B), concluding with :

> $\exists y\forall x(P(x)→Q(y))$.

Finally, by $\rightarrow$-introduction :

> > $\vdash (∀x∃y(P(x)→Q(y))) \rightarrow (\exists y\forall x(P(x)→Q(y)))$.

---

We may check it, showing that the formula is *valid* using the *tableaux method* [see Raymond Smullyan, [First-Order Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486683702) (1968 - Dover reprint)].

*(1)* $∀x∃y(P(x)→Q(y))$

*(2)* $\lnot (\exists y\forall x(P(x)→Q(y))$

*(3)* $\lnot \forall x(P(x)→Q(a))$ --- *rule C* on (2) with $a$

*(4)* $\lnot (P(b)→Q(a))$ --- *rule D* on (3) with $b$ *new*

*(5)* $Pb$ --- from (4)

*(6)* $\lnot Qa$ --- from (4)

*(7)* $\exists y(P(b)→Q(y))$ --- *rule C* on (1) with $b$

*(8)* $P(b)→Q(c)$ --- *rule D* on (7) with $c$ *new*

*(9a)* $\lnot Pb$ --- from (8) : **closed** with (5)

*(9b)* $Qc$ --- from (8) : **open**

*(10)* $\lnot \forall x(P(x)→Q(c))$ --- *rule C* on (2) with $c$

*(11)* $\lnot (P(d)→Q(c))$ --- *rule D* on (10) with $d$ *new*

*(12)* $Pd$ --- from (11)

*(13)* $\lnot Qc$ --- from (11) : **closed** witth (9b).

Thus :

> > $∀x∃y(P(x)→Q(y)) \vDash \exists y\forall x(P(x)→Q(y))$.

---

*Appendix*

We can prove it also in "Hilbert-style"; following Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122384520) (2nd - 2001).

*(1)* $∀x∃y(P(x)→Q(y))$

*(2)* $∃y(P(c)→Q(y))$ --- where $c$ is a new *constant*, by *Ax-2* [page 112]

*(3)* $P(c)→∃yQ(y)$ --- by (Q2B) [page 130], $y$ **not** free in $P(c)$

*(4)* $P(c)$ --- assumed

*(5)* $∃yQ(y)$ --- by *modus ponens*

*(6)* $\Gamma, ∃xP(x) \vdash ∃yQ(y)$ --- where $\Gamma = \{ ∀x∃y(P(x)→Q(y)) \}$,

by **Corollary 24H (Rule EI)** [page 124 : Assume that the constant symbol $c$ does 
not occur in $\varphi, \psi$, or $\Gamma$, and that $\Gamma, \varphi[x/c] \vdash \psi$. Then $\Gamma, \exists x \varphi \vdash \psi$ and there is a deduction of $\psi$ from $\Gamma, \exists x \varphi$ in which $c$ does not occur.]

*(7)* $\Gamma \vdash ∃xP(x) \rightarrow ∃yQ(y)$ --- by *Deduction Theorem* [page 118]

*(8)* $\Gamma \vdash \exists y(∃xP(x) \rightarrow Q(y))$ --- by (Q2B) [page 130], $y$ **not** free in $∃xP(x)$

*(9)* $\Gamma \vdash \exists y \forall x(P(x) \rightarrow Q(y))$ --- by (Q3A) [page 122], $x$ **not** free in $Q(y)$, and some tedious passages for *replacement*.

Thus :

> $∀x∃y(P(x)→Q(y)) \vdash \exists y \forall x(P(x) \rightarrow Q(y))$.

Comment: This would be easier to read for me if you wrote out the full names for the calculus axioms you used; I always have to look up "$\forall$-E" and so on.