# Show that $ \forall{x}\exists{y}{(P(x) \to Q(y))} \vdash \exists{y}\forall{x}{(P(x) \to Q(y))} $

Tags: predicate-logic, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I need to show that

$$ \forall{x}\exists{y}{(P(x) \to Q(y))} \vdash \exists{y}\forall{x}{(P(x) \to Q(y))} $$

using the natural deduction rules outlined in [Logic in Computer Science: Modelling and Reasoning about Systems](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=975331) by Michael Huth and Mark Ryan.

There is a proof outlined in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828398/natural-deduction-%E2%88%80x%E2%88%83y-px-%E2%86%92-qy-%E2%86%92-%E2%88%83y%E2%88%80xpx-%E2%86%92-qy). However, it seems to violate the scope requirements for $\forall{}$ introduction, as outlined in the book.

Comment: Are you sure the formula is correct?

Comment: Should they not be equivalent? $\vdash \psi \rightarrow \phi$ is equivalent to $\psi \vdash \phi$ and because of soundness, $\psi \vDash \phi$ no?

Comment: I did realise that I miswrote P(y) when I meant Q(y) in the original question, I've corrected that now

Comment: When you speak of natural deduction rules, you probably rather want to show $\forall{x}\exists{y}{(P(x) \to Q(y))} \vdash \exists{y}\forall{x}{(P(x) \to Q(y))}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that one is nasty!  Using the Prenex Laws their equivalence is easily demonstrated, but proving those Prenex laws can be a pain.  You'll need to use a proof by contradiction. Here is a proof that is quite similar ... and using very similar rules as well.

[image]

OK, here's the actual proof:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is great, but this proves it for $P(x) v Q(y)$ instead of $P(x) \rightarrow Q(y)$, but I suppose it's somewhat equivalent / the proof will be similar. Out of interest, what did you use to generate this proof?

Comment: @TheConfuZzledDude Yes, I actually did the proof for what you want yesterday, and it is very similar. The program I use here is called Fitch ... it is not free, unfortunately; it comes iwht the textbook Language, Proof, and Logic

Comment: Thanks, I adapted your proof to the question, and used FitchJS to check it

Comment: On line 19, `b` is used outside of its declaration scope.

Comment: @GrahamKemp In this particular proof system you can introduce variable-free terms for $\forall \ Elim$ as well as $\bot \ Elim$ without having to declare a specific scope for them. So yes, I used a $b$ as an arbitrary individual in lines $3$ through $10$, but I specifically introduced it since this was used for a $\forall \ Elim$. But on line $19$ it was obtained from a $\bot \ Elim$, and in this proof system that's ok.

Answer (score 2):

A proof of the problem given, adapted from @Bram28's answer

[image: Proof]

Comment: Good work!  I did the second part a little more quickly. I'l add my proof to my Answer

Comment: @Bram28 Line 25 looks suspect to me.  Term `c` is used outside of its Flag scope.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Same here ... the $Qc$ on line $25$ comes from a $\bot \ Elim$, which this system allows: *any* statement follows from a contradiction ... and it does not effect the validity of the subproof on ines $3$ through $12$, since line $25$ comes only after that subproof.  But I can understand that in some proof systems the use of temporary terms used in a $\forall \ Intro$ proof is restricted to that very subproof, just to avoid any possible confusion.