# Predicate logic proof by natural deduction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, predicate-logic

∀ ∃ (() ∨ ()) ⊢ ∃ ∀ (() ∨ ())

I first introduced y0 as a fresh variable and then introduced x0 as fresh variable but still not able to prove correctly following the rules of Natural Deduction.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I am trying to prove the above predicate logic proof by natural deduction rules but I am unable to. The link sent above prove other way round which I also proved on my own

Comment: @Physor there is such proof that too in stack exchange but it is violating natural deduction rules. Refer to the link : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828398/natural-deduction-%E2%88%80x%E2%88%83y-px-%E2%86%92-qy-%E2%86%92-%E2%88%83y%E2%88%80xpx-%E2%86%92-qy